# How to extract my case class from Json using Json4s?

Tags: json, scala, unmarshalling, case-class, json4s

In an akka scala applicatoon I consume a rest endpoint. Hence, I want to map its responses to case classes, yet I also want to ease working with those case classes by transforming certain properties, e.g. those containing dates.

So given a Json:

```
{
    "id": "20180213165959sCdJr",
    "createdAt": "2018-02-13T16:59:59.570+0000",
    "finishedAt": "2018-02-13T17:00:18.118+0000"
}
```

I want to create such a clase class out of it:

```
case class FinishedRun
(
  id: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  finishedAt: Date
)
```

I created this construtor:

```
object FinishedRun {

  def apply(id: String,
            createdAt: String,
            finishedAt: String
           ): FinishedRun = {

    val getDate = (jsonValue: String) => {
      val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
      format.parse(jsonValue)
    }


    new FinishedRun(id, createdAt = getDate(createdAt), finishedAt = getDate(finishedAt))
  }
}
```

While this works for initializing a case class from scratch, I have trouble extracting this case class with the help of the json4s libary through the `parse(json).as[FinishedRun]` approach.

It appears that json4s does not call the case class' constructor and hence cannot extract it, throwing:

```
No usable value for createdAt
Invalid date '2018-02-13T16:59:59.570+0000'
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for createdAt
Invalid date '2018-02-13T16:59:59.570+0000'
    at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:95)
```

What am I missing to have Json4s parse the Date properly?

---

Here is my test case:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec


class MarshallingTest extends FlatSpec {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  it should "marshall json object with date iso strings into a case class with Date properties" in {
    val json =
      """
        |{
        |    "id": "20180213165959sCdJr",
        |    "createdAt": "2018-02-13T16:59:59.570+0000",
        |    "finishedAt": "2018-02-13T17:00:18.118+0000"
        |}
      """.stripMargin

    val expected = FinishedRun(
      id = "20180213165959sCdJr",
      createdAt = "2018-02-13T16:59:59.570+0000",
      finishedAt = "2018-02-13T17:00:18.118+0000"
    )
    val actual = parse(json).extract[FinishedRun]

    assert(actual == expected)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your [CustomSerializer(1)](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types), [CustomSerializer(2)](http://queirozf.com/entries/json4s-examples-common-basic-operations-using-jackson-as-backend#custom-serializer). I changed the date type from [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html):

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonAST._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

case class FinishedRun
(
  id: String,
  createdAt: ZonedDateTime,
  finishedAt: ZonedDateTime
)

object FinishedRunSerializer {
  val dateTimeFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
}

class FinishedRunSerializer extends CustomSerializer[FinishedRun](
  format => ( {
    case jObj: JObject =>
      implicit val fmt = format
      val id = (jObj \ "id").extract[String]
      val created = ZonedDateTime.parse((jObj \ "createdAt").extract[String],
        FinishedRunSerializer.dateTimeFmt)
      val finished = ZonedDateTime.parse((jObj \ "finishedAt").extract[String],
        FinishedRunSerializer.dateTimeFmt)
      FinishedRun(id, created, finished)
  }, {
    case finishedRun: FinishedRun =>
      ("id" -> finishedRun.id) ~
        ("createdAt" -> finishedRun.createdAt.format(FinishedRunSerializer.dateTimeFmt)) ~
        ("finishedAt" -> finishedRun.finishedAt.format(FinishedRunSerializer.dateTimeFmt))
  }
  ))
```

In your test or the place when you use it do not forget to bring `FinishedRunSerializer`:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new FinishedRunSerializer()
```

Comment: This answer works, yet it implies that the JSON is ordered properly. If one has a json object where `id` occures last instead of first, this would break. Furthermore, it requires changing to `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I've updated the code. It does not depend on the order. If you want to have information about time zone, ZonedDateTime is right type.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem might be to use the *Serialization* trait in *org.json4s*. You should be able to do something like this:

```
val finishedRun = read[FinishedRun](json)
```

Please refer to this link for details and examples: https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-polymorphic-lists